# Why doesn't my reset function reset the timer when I call clearHistory()?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm making a google extension that will track and storage the amount of time I spend on different site to a local storage. I'm trying to add a clear function where it will clear all the local storage and reset the timer back to 00:00:00 on the current site. Right now I have the function working clearing all the local storage, but it doesn't reset the timer back to 00:00:00. Here is my code base.
popup.js

```
import storageModule from "./src/JS/storage.js";
import clockModule from "./src/JS/clock.js";
const resetButtonElement = document.querySelector('.clear');
const clockElement = document.querySelector('.clock');
const hostnameElement = document.querySelector('.hostname');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Open a connection to the background script
    const port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'popupConnection' });

    // Listen for messages from the background script
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
        if (message.hostname) {
            hostnameElement.textContent = message.hostname;
        }

        if (message.clock) {
            
            clockElement.textContent = message.clock;
        }

    });

    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const time = urlParams.get('time');
    clockElement.textContent = time;

    // Add an event listener to detect when the popup is closed
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
        port.disconnect();
    });
});

resetButtonElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    storageModule.clearHistory(function() {
        clockModule.resetTimeClock();
        clockElement.textContent="00:00:00"
    });
});
```

clock.js

```
import { setPopClock } from "./popupUI.js";
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;
// Clock function
function updateClock() {
    seconds++;

    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    const hoursStr = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const minutesStr = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const secondsStr = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');

    const clock = `${hoursStr}:${minutesStr}:${secondsStr}`;
    
    setTimeClock(clock);
    setPopClock(clock);
}

// Function to set the current time clock
function setTimeClock(timeClock) {
    const [h, m, s] = timeClock.split(':').map(Number);
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
    seconds = s;
}

// Function to get the current time clock
function getTimeClock() {
    return `${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
}

// Function to reset the time clock
function resetTimeClock() {
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}

const clockModule = {
    updateClock,
    setTimeClock,
    getTimeClock,
    resetTimeClock,
};

export default clockModule;
```

storage.js

```
import clockModule from "./clock.js";

// Function to update and store hostname-clock pairs in chrome.storage.local
function updateAndStoreHostnameClockPair(hostname, clock) {
    const data = {};
    data[hostname] = clock;

    chrome.storage.local.set(data, function () {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
            console.log(`Data stored for ${hostname}`);
        }
    });
}

// Function to retrieve hostname-clock pairs from chrome.storage.local
function retrieveHostnameClockPairs(callback) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (result) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
            console.log("Retrieved data from storage:", result);
            callback(result);
        }
    });

    
}

function clearHistory(callback) {
     // Reset the clock immediately

    // Clear the local storage after the clock has been reset
    chrome.storage.local.clear(function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
            console.log("Storage cleared successfully");
            callback();
        }
        // Call the callback function to update the clock in the popup
        
    });
    
}


const storageModule = {
    updateAndStoreHostnameClockPair,
    retrieveHostnameClockPairs,
    clearHistory,
};

export default storageModule;
```

I tried calling the reset timer function right after and before the clearHistory function, but for somereason, the timer would still runs from the previous clock instead of starting from 00:00:00.This is before the clearhistory function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY18g.png), and after [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7LZ8.png). As you can see, it clear the local storage for all the site I have visted besides the one I'm currently on, is there anyway I can clear the current site timer and reset it to 00:00:00 as well? Please help